# How to apply theme features which provides to pages with Custom Post Type

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

We have used Eduma theme for building our wordpress website. Actually we don't want themes features that they provides to implement courses. That is why we don't used those inbuilt plugins for their features.

As per our requirement, I have created a custom-post-type for "Courses" and I had applied all the page features and attributes to make same like page.

Even i have used custom-template to make our course page, and for that i have just used themes page.php code for the same.
Below is the code for custom-page-template.

```
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('content', 'page'); ?>

    <?php
    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
    if (comments_open() || get_comments_number()) :
        comments_template();
    endif;
    ?>

<?php endwhile; // end of the loop.  ?>
```

In the above code they don't used get_sidebar(), and our custom-template takes by default sidebar widget which shows blank space instead of full-width.

I want our custom-template should be with full-width (no sidebar).

Could you please suggest us, what we can do with the above code to hide our sidebar for "Courses" cuatom-post-type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to hide the side bar with CSS for those post types only. Your custom post type should have it's own class so target that, hide the sidebar and make the content area 100% width. Post the html output or a link maybe but something like below will work.

```
.custom-post-class .sidebar{display:none}
.content{width:100%;}
```

You could also do it with JS and just remove it.